# Realm Object fields are nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, realm, optional-values

I'm having a strange issue with objects in `Realm`. When i fetch an object from Realm database at first time & deleted object from database. unwrapping an optional value `nil`.

Model:

```
class Outlet: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id:string = ""
    @objc dynamic var name:string = ""
    @objc dynamic var name1:Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var name2:Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var name3:Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var name4:Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var name5:Int = 0

    let  OutletListS = List<OutletList>()
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Class:

```
class DBManager {

    private var database: Realm

    static let sharedInstance = DBManager()

    private init() {
        database = try! Realm()
    }

    func getDataFromDB() -> Outlet {
        let result = database.objects(Outlet.self)
        return result.first!
    } 

}
```

and calling method:

```
let selectedOutlet = DBManager.sharedInstance.getDataFromDB()
```

**Error:**

```
Printing description of result:
Results <0x7fb64f02c230> (

)
```

i could't solve it myself. help me please.

Comment: `return result.first!` your function is presuming that there will always be objects in the database? is this the case? there will *never* be 0 items returned?

Comment: @Scriptable There is no objects in the database at first time while fetch database . I'm checking object, i added object if nil & checking , update object items if object there.

Comment: in getDataFromDB() try: return database.objects(Outlet.self).first! But I think the problem is somewhere in your model class. Share Outlet class please

Comment: @M.Wojcik, Yes, I updated my post. can you check modal class please.

Comment: now check it please

Comment: Doesn't primary key have to return the same name inside "" as one of variables? Like return "id" ? You don't have any 'olid' variable

Comment: sorry, by mistake. I have set correct. tell me what is the issue here, why it's crashing , when i was fetch Realm database please.

Comment: Ok I think I finally know where is the problem. After some tests I found out that when you fetch something from database to an object and than delete that record from the database there will be always problem while getting to that object. It's like realm record is the "main object" and fetching is like a making reference to it.. And when you delete that object from database there is no way that object u fetched can still access it

Comment: You can try to make a other variable, like (var holder) and than when getting  "let selectedOutlet = DBManager.sharedInstance.getDataFromDB()" just make : "holder = selectedOutlet". After that you can delete the instance from database and access holder

Comment: @M.Wojcik I'm fetching data from database on "ViewDidAppear" method at first time. It's necessary  to check database in my class every time user entered Screen.  Yes, I declared as "var" as you said.    **Code**  `var selectedOutlet  =  Outle()   selectedOutlet =  DBManager.sharedInstance.getDataFromDB()`   .This line goes to error. what is wrong here. I had been tried with it. I had stuck here.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that when you fetch an object like this: "var selectedOutlet = DBManager.sharedInstance.getDataFromDB()" and than delete it from database (you said u are deleting it right?), than if you try to access 'selectedOutlet' you will always get 'nil', cause it has been deleted from db and also the reference saved in 'selectedOutlet'. Thats how realmdb works. Thats why you should make another variable into which you will refer: 'var otherVariable = selectedOutlet'